# Remove Selected Item of a Dropdown from Other Dropdowns with Same Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a set of dropdowns which are populated by a json object on load. And I need every selected item from any control be removed from the rest of the control. 
My approach here is simple

1. To clear store the selected value and the name of the selected
   control in variables.
2. Loop through the dropdown controls on the page and clear their
   contents but skip the selected control.
3. In the same loop, loop through the json object and fill the empty
   dropdowns with data except the item that matches the selected item

But when I wrote the following code below, It only cleared the next control and did nothing else. Please take a look

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropDownDest" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd2" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd3" class="dropdown">
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var json = {
cars: [
     {
        "CarType": "BMW",
        "carID": "bmw123"
     },
     {
        "CarType": "mercedes",
        "carID": "merc123"
     },
     {
        "CarType": "volvo",
        "carID": "vol123r"
     },
     {
        "CarType": "ford",
        "carID": "ford123"
     }
   ]
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON("/echo/json/",function(obj)
    {
        $.each(json.cars,function(key,value)
        {
            var option = $('<option />').val(value.carID).text(value.CarType);
            $('.dropdown').append(option);
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $('.dropdown').change(function(){
            var selectedValue = $("option:selected", this).val();
            var elementName = ($(this).attr('id'));
            $('.dropdown').each(function(){
                if ($(this).attr('id') != elementName){
                    $(this).empty();
                    $.each(json.cars, function(key,value){
                        if (json.cars[key].carID != selectedValue){
                            var optionn = $('<option />').val(value.carID).text(value.CarType);
                            $(this).append(optionn);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Please Help me out. This is the second day on this.

Comment: so you want to remove the selected item from rest  of the select tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `$(this)`, that made the problems, so i added `t,q` to `$('.dropdown').each(function(t,q) {})`

Then `$(q).append(optionn);` works

```js
var json = {
  cars: [{
      "CarType": "BMW",
      "carID": "bmw123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "mercedes",
      "carID": "merc123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "volvo",
      "carID": "vol123r"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "ford",
      "carID": "ford123"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(json.cars, function(key, value) {
    var option = $('<option />').val(value.carID).text(value.CarType);
    $('.dropdown').append(option);
  });

  $(function() {
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
      var selectedValue = $("option:selected", this).val();
      var elementName = ($(this).attr('id'));
      $('.dropdown').each(function(t,q) {
        if ($(q).attr('id') != elementName) {
          $(q).empty();
          $.each(json.cars, function(key, value) {
            if (json.cars[key].carID != selectedValue) {
              var optionn = $('<option />').val(value.carID).text(value.CarType);
              $(q).append(optionn);
            }
          });
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDownDest" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd2" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd3" class="dropdown">
</select>
```

**Update** added code so you cant select any of the previous values.

```js
var json = {
  cars: [{
      "CarType": "BMW",
      "carID": "bmw123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "mercedes",
      "carID": "merc123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "volvo",
      "carID": "vol123r"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "ford",
      "carID": "ford123"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(json.cars, function(key, value) {
    var option = $('<option />').val(value.carID).text(value.CarType);
    $('.dropdown').append(option);
  });

  $(function() {
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
      var selectedValue = $("option:selected", this).val();
      var elementName = ($(this).attr('id'));
      var arr = [];
      $(this).prevAll(".dropdown").each(function(i, t) {
        arr.push($("option:selected", t).val())
      })
      arr.push(selectedValue)
      $(this).nextAll(".dropdown").each(function(t, q) {
        if ($(q).attr('id') != elementName) {
          $(q).empty();
          $.each(json.cars, function(key, value) {
            if ($.inArray(json.cars[key].carID, arr)== -1) {
              var optionn = $('<option />').val(value.carID).text(value.CarType);
              $(q).append(optionn);
            }
          });
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDownDest" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd2" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd3" class="dropdown">
</select>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so very much! But could you explain why I can't use `$(this)` to achieve the desired result?

Comment: `$(this)` is refering to `$('.dropdown').change(function() {})`

Comment: Thank you very much! Noted.

Answer (score 1):

First of you don't need a nested doc ready. And this can be done in your case:

```js
var json = {
  cars: [{
      "CarType": "BMW",
      "carID": "bmw123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "mercedes",
      "carID": "merc123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "volvo",
      "carID": "vol123r"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "ford",
      "carID": "ford123"
    }
  ]
};

$.each(json.cars, function(i, item) {
  $('.dropdown').append($('<option>', {
    value: item.carID,
    text: item.CarType
  }));
})

$('.dropdown').change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $("option:selected", this).val();
  var elementName = ($(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).siblings('.dropdown').find('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDownDest" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd2" class="dropdown">
</select>
<select id="dd3" class="dropdown">
</select>
```

Comment: shorter and cleaner! Although doesn't get updated from the datasource. But I love the solution. Many thanks.